# Syntax error on simple if condition (if partychoice = R:)

Tags: python

New programmer, working in python 2.7.

With this code, I get a syntax error in the line 'if partychoice = R, stating the '=' is invalid syntax. How come it won;t let me assign the variable.

Also, I'm sure there are tons of other errors, but I have to start somewhere.

```
print "Welcome to 'Pass the Bill', where you will take on the role of a professional lobbyist trying to guide a bill through Congress and get it signed into law by the President!"
start = raw_input(str ('Press Y to continue:'))
print 'Great, lets get started!'
partychoice = raw_input (str("Would you like to be a Republican or Democrat? Type 'R' for Republican or 'D' for Democrat."))
if partychoice = R:
    print 'Ah, the Grand old Party of Lincoln and Reagan. Great Choice!'
    replegchoice = raw_input (str("What type of bill what you like congress to introduce? Restrictions on abortions, lower income taxes, easier access to automatic weapons, private health plans, or stricter immigration laws? ( A = abortion restrictions, L = lower taxes, AW = automatic weapons, H = private health plans, S = stricter immigration laws'))
    if replegchoice = A or a
            print 'A controversial choice, despite support of most Republicans, you are sure to face opposition from Democrats in Congress!'
    if replegchoice = L or l
            print 'A popular idea, Republicans in Congress are sure to support this idea, as will many American voters!'
    if replegchoice = AW, aw, Aw, or AW
            print 'Rural, midwest, and small town voters will love this, as will most Republicans in Congress. Democrats and voters in urban cities will surely be less supportive.'
    if replegchoice = H or h
            print 'Eimination of Medicare, Medicaid, and Obamacare! Republicans generally like the idea of making each person responsible for paying their own health care costs'
    if replegchoice = S or s
            print 'a popular idea supported by president Trump, this is sure face strong opposition from democrats and many voters.'
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: it should be `==` instead of `=`, ie `if partychoice == 'R'`, same goes to the nested `if`s

Comment: Change your title. It's not related to your question

Comment: Aside: if you're a new programmer you should be starting with Python 3.

Comment: BTW, if you want folks to "be gentle", a good place to start going forward is reading and following the local rules. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, for instance -- a good question incorporating code has **the shortest possible code** that will produce the same problem. That means if you can produce it with only one `if` statement, you should include nothing but that one `if` statement (and any assignments mandatory to make that statement operable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace "=" with "==" in the statement:

```
if partychoice = R:"
```

"=" is an assignment operator
"==" is an equality operator

e.g.

```
#assign something to a variable 
x = 5
print x
>>5

#compare for equality
y = 6
if y == 6:
    print y
else:
    print "y is not 6"
>>6
```

Be sure to use informative titles in future posts, something that relates to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to

```
if partychoice == 'R':
```

First you need to use two '=' characters. One '=' sets a variable, two compares for equality.

Second you want to compare the variable `partychoice` to the string "R" so you need quotes. Without quotes it thinks you're comparing a reference to another object.

Answer (score 0):

For *CONDITIONALS* you need to use comparison operator `==` not the assignment operator which is `=`.

Check this out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code:

1. You are using the assignment operator, `=`, instead of the comparative operator, `==`.
2. You need to remember to use `'` when containing and comparing strings, currently you are comparing them with the variable `R` instead of the letter `'R'`
3. I removed the superfulous `str()` conversion inside the `raw_input` function.  This isn't needed as `""` defines a string.
4. You should simply call the `.lower()` function on the results that way you only have to check the lower case version of the string.  It will save you a lot of time.

   ```
   print "Welcome to 'Pass the Bill', where you will take on the role of a professional lobbyist trying to guide a bill through Congress and get it signed into law by the President!"
   start = raw_input('Press Y to continue:')
   print 'Great, lets get started!'
   partychoice = raw_input("Would you like to be a Republican or Democrat? Type 'R' for Republican or 'D' for Democrat.").lower()
   if partychoice == 'r':
       print 'Ah, the Grand old Party of Lincoln and Reagan. Great Choice!'
       replegchoice = raw_input ("What type of bill what you like congress to introduce? Restrictions on abortions, lower income taxes, easier access to automatic weapons, private health plans, or stricter immigration laws? ( A = abortion restrictions, L = lower taxes, AW = automatic weapons, H = private health plans, S = stricter immigration laws")
       if replegchoice == 'a':
               print 'A controversial choice, despite support of most Republicans, you are sure to face opposition from Democrats in Congress!'
       if replegchoice == 'l':
               print 'A popular idea, Republicans in Congress are sure to support this idea, as will many American voters!'
       if replegchoice == 'aw':
               print 'Rural, midwest, and small town voters will love this, as will most Republicans in Congress. Democrats and voters in urban cities will surely be less supportive.'
       if replegchoice == 'h':
               print 'Eimination of Medicare, Medicaid, and Obamacare! Republicans generally like the idea of making each person responsible for paying their own health care costs'
       if replegchoice == 's':
               print 'a popular idea supported by president Trump, this is sure face strong opposition from democrats and many voters.'
   ```

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: Hey if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot. (click the green tick)